# Wrong data display when i set multiple series type in highstock chart

Tags: highcharts

I try to make a chart with multiple series type, lines and column.
Exemple here :[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wxujmhxk/)

```
$(function () {
var seriesOptions = [],
    seriesCounter = 0,
    names = ['MSFT', 'AAPL', 'GOOG'];

/**
 * Create the chart when all data is loaded
 * @returns {undefined}
 */
function createChart() {

    $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {

        rangeSelector: {
            selected: 4
        },

        yAxis: {
            labels: {
                formatter: function () {
                    return (this.value > 0 ? ' + ' : '') + this.value + '%';
                }
            },
            plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 2,
                color: 'silver'
            }]
        },

        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                compare: 'percent'
            }
        },

        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}</span>: <b>{point.y}</b> ({point.change}%)<br/>',
            valueDecimals: 2
        },

        series: seriesOptions
    });
}

$.each(names, function (i, name) {

    $.getJSON('https://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=' + name.toLowerCase() + '-c.json&callback=?',    function (data) {

        seriesOptions[i] = {
            name: name,
            data: data,
        };
        if(name == 'GOOG'){
            seriesOptions[i].type = 'column';
        }

        // As we're loading the data asynchronously, we don't know what order it will arrive. So
        // we keep a counter and create the chart when all the data is loaded.
        seriesCounter += 1;

        if (seriesCounter === names.length) {
            createChart();
        }
    });
});
```

});

When i'm not zooming i have wrong data (more than normal) and when i zoom in i have the good data.

what is the problem ? i don't know why the serie type can change datas

Thanks for you help !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Defaulty the Highstock uses the [dataGrouping](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.series.dataGrouping.enabled), which groups points according to units. You can disable that by the parameter.

```
plotOptions:{
   series:{
      dataGrouping:{
          enabled: true
      }
   }
}
```